# sharepoint 2010, customized sp ribbon javascript file is not loading properly in chrome....any inputs????

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have customized ribbon(js scripts) that loads properly in IE and firefox but in google chrome(which is a requirement to use it due to its high response time) it does not load the ribbon at the first instance. However, it loads after several page load refreshes(Ctrl + F5). If anyone come across this issue, provide your inputs. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint and IIS are always trying to cache resource, to ensure application performace. When you're doing SharePoint Development you've always to ensure that cache is cleared.

Especially when you're working with the SharePoint ribbon it's required to clear the cache before accessing the website after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using CKS tools for deployment from VS2010 you have to ensure that files are copied to the SharePoint Root. Sometimes I get an exception when they try to overwrite JS files in the SharePoint root, because sharepoint has a handle on them.

When doing SharePoint development I always copy *.resx and *.js by hand.

Comment: Please elaborate doesn't SharePoint root folder mean 14 hive (which we already have files there) or the application folder?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the rendering of the search box control in Google Chrome. Try adding 'Visible="false"' to the 'SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"' control on the master page. This corrects the rendering issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is officially not built to work in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my webkit (chrome and safari) browser issues such as scrolling and the ribbon loading with this nice script http://goo.gl/1OUlI. Ended up being a timing issue. Hope it helps you out. I see this is a bit old but no best answer.